# printing values in array pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I can't seem to wrap my head around a problem. What am I missing?

Consider the following

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    while ( *argv ) {
        printf("argv[] is: %s\n", *argv);
        ++argv;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out every value of argv. So a command line such as `./example arg1 arg2` would output the following:

```
`argv[] is: ./example`
`argv[] is: arg1`
`argv[] is: arg2`
```

Now consider the following (which I am having trouble with):

```
int main(void) {
    char *days[] = {
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday"
    };
    while ( *days ) {
        printf("day is %s\n", *days);
        *days++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile, I get error `cannot increment value of type 'char *[3]'`

If I change `*days++` to `(*days)++` it compiles. If I run it, it runs forever and eventually fails with `bus error`.

However, it does not iterate through every value of `days[]`. I even tried putting in a Null pointer in the form of `'\0'` and `"\0"` in the days array to no effect.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://ideone.com/GM4wIN

Comment: See `++argv;`  vs `*days++;`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several errors in your code:

1. There is difference between variable `argv` and constant `days`. Variable can be changed, constant array label - cannot.
2. In your array, terminator NULL is missing at the end of the array.
3. `*days++;` is senseless in this case. This is a dummy and returns value of `days`, and increment `days` thereafter. It is enough to just use `days++`.

Thus, your code must be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *days[] = {
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        NULL
    };

    // Your style
    char **d = days;
    while ( *d ) {
        printf("day is %s\n", *d);
        d++;
    }

    // Or, more "scholastic" code
    for(const char **d = days; *d; d++)
        printf("day is %s\n", *d);

    return 0;
```

Comment: ok, so when I declared char *days[] I didn't actually create a pointer, i created an array? is that why you had to put the array in a pointer named *d ? so I can thus use pointer arithmnatic?

Comment: Yes. If you would like know details, build your program with option -S, and review assembly code.

Comment: `days` is a variable, not a constant. There is a rule that array variables cannot be incremented.

Comment: `const char **d = days;` is an error, there is no implicit conversion from `char **` to `const char **`  . To use that code you would also have to declare the array as `const char *days[]` .

Answer (score 6):

The argv[] structure contains a null pointer as the last entry which is why your code works.  You can add a null pointer to your data structure.  You also need to realize that argv is a parameter (just like a local variable) that points to the internal data structure holding the command line arguments.  You need to create a similar local variable that can iterate through the array.

Here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char *days[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 0 };
    char **v = days;

  while (v) {
    printf("day is %s\n", *v);
    v++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, why the double asterix **v? is it a pointer to a pointer? i've yet to see ** in any examples

Comment: @fizzydrink: In your code you have a function parameter definition `char *argv[]`, which its context is the same as `char ** argv`. Just replace it, recompile and become enlightened.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to increment the character pointer, you should probably loop through each element in the character array.

For example:

```
char *days[] = {
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday"
};
int i;    
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    printf("day is %s\n", days[i]);
```

Comment: The 3 should perhaps be replaced by `sizeof(days) / sizeof(days[0])`, or an enumeration constant `enum { NUM_DAYS = sizeof(days) / sizeof(days[0]) };` or something similar.  Or use a sentinel NULL pointer to mark the end of the data, as with `argv` when passed to `main()` — but notice that the arguments to `main()` are redundant since you could determine `argc` by iterating through `argv` (or you could omit the NULL element at the end of `argv`), but it is more convenient to have the redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

1. `days` is a 2D character array. Though the name of the array points to the first address, it is not a pointer. You can not do pointer arithmetic on an array name.
2. `while ( *days )` will never become false. You should change the logic.

In the below code I have retained most of your code.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
        char *days[] = {
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday"
        };

       for(int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("day is %s\n", (days[i]));
        }

        return 0;
```